# How to setup AWS Amazon MQ with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, aws

Magento v2.3 has been added supported for ampq message queues.  I wonder how one could go about using it with AWS SQS or Amazon MQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will not work at the moment.

**In short words:**
Magento2 use php-amqplib as lib.
And php-amqplib uses AMQP 0.9.1.
And Amazon MQ uses AMQP 1.0.

These are complete different protocols.

**Related issue on github:**
https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/757#issuecomment-555128572